# Shared Memory between process and corruption

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a number of programs that I'm adding error reporting for.  My plan is to create a watchdog app that spawns when one of them is launched and sits idle waiting for one of the main apps to crash so that it can generate a dump.  I'm using a shared memory file between them to communicate when a crash occurs and the crash is caught using ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter.

So, here is my question --

Say I have 3 programs open plus the watchdog.

If A crashes, is it possible for it to introduce instability/corruption in B and C because of the memory they all share?  I assume if the problem occurs in the shared memory this would be the case, but what about if the exception occurs in other places?  The memory block is only accessed on application launch and after the exception occurs.  Is there anything I can do to reduce the possibility of this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: The programs should be aware about the corruption possibility and use some kind of heuristics (magic numbers, strings should always end in '\0')  to determine it and reset the values.

Comment: Is shared memory the best choice for inter-process communication if you're worried about some of the processes crashing?  Sockets or pipes might be safer...

Comment: " I'm using a shared memory file between them to communicate when a crash occurs" - what do you need to communicate ? I think you should do the least possible in the exception handler (dump crash related data in a file) and exit. This unexpected exit will be observed by the watchdog.

Comment: And sockets or pipes are safer

Comment: But pipes and sockets are not suitable if the amount of shared data is too large. Anyway if you are using shared memory, this should be kind of protected by the use of semaphores.